# Private information can be decompiled

Tags: c#

I have my database information saved on a string in clear text, if someone decompile my application its possible to get that information?
If yes there are ways to prevent that?

Comment: Yeah, don't store security-sensitive information in clear text!

Comment: 1. use windows authentication (preferred), else 2. Encrypt string and obfuscate your app (only stops casual prying, not secure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  It's not even hard.

If you are trying to hid a secret from your user, give up.  A sufficiently dedicated user will win.  You can look at the windows Data Protection API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) but its only a speed bump.  If you have to keep it a secret, keep it on your own server.